# ASIHTTPRequest Removing Header information

Tags: iphone, header, asihttprequest

Sorry in advance for the newbie question.
I am using ASIHTTPRequest to send and receive packets.
However, when I send a packet from the client to the server, the packet has a header attached to it:

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.6:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 64
User-Agent: ASIHTTPRequestTests 1.0 (iPod touch; iPhone OS 4.1; ko_KR)
Connection: close

PACKET_TESTM0001

The only information I want my client to send is: PACKET_TESTM0001

Is there a way to remove all the above header (All lines including POST to User-Agent)
Thanks in advance for your helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

That header is required by the HTTP protocol, so better you don't remove it or your web server will not accept the request.

If you do no want to use the HTTP protocol (i.e., you do not want to talk to a web server), then you can use [NSStreams with sockets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI).

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion here between "packet" and "HTTP request". Googling those two terms would probably be enlightening for you.

ASIHTTPRequest makes, as the name implies, HTTP requests. It wants to be talking to an HTTP server, and then probably to some sort of server-side code to process the request.

Have you rolled your own server, here? Because you're not doing what is expected when you're talking HTTP.